# Shared Windows Folder

Tags: camera, share

I'm doing this beginners project with a motion sensor and a pi camera. With this I'll make a security camera. Since the SD card is really large on memory (compared to a HDD) I want the pi to send all my images/videos to my main (Windows 7) PC. I was thinking of a shared folder on the main PC, I do know how to make a shared folder on windows. But how do I do 'upload' images to this  folder from the raspberry pi? Or are there better ways to do this. The Pi is connected to a LAN network.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Install SAMBA

```
sudo apt-get install samba
```

Then create a directory in your mnt folder, and mount your Windows share to the folder. Make sure your windows share allows ananoymous or myuser read and write without password

```
su (make sure you do this as root)
mkdir /mnt/linky_share
mount -t cifs -o user=myuser //192.168.1.104/share /mnt/samba_share
<enter>
```

This mount will only last until reboot - So once you get it right open the file `/etc/fstab` and add the line

```
//192.168.1.104/share /mnt/samba_share smbfs username=myuser 0 0
```

Comment: I have disabled passwords for shared folders but when I use this command: `mount -t cifs -o user=pi //IPadress-PC/foldername /mnt/linky_share` (i've changed it a bit so you can also check if I use the command correctly) but then it asks for a password

Comment: @sweer edit your /etc/samba/smb.conf and replace the security = user line as security = share then restart samba service.

Comment: @gurcanozturk I figured out the password part but now it gives me an error: `Error(115): Operation now in progress`

Comment: @SWeer are you running a firewall on PC or RPi?

Comment: only one thing. When I want to write a file to /mnt/linky_share with python (running IDLE as root ofc) I get a permission denied. So I do not have the rights to make a new file or directory in this directory

Answer (score 2):

You can create a shared directory on Windows in the normal way. (If you don't know how to do this the Pi site is not the best place to ask).

The Pi can connect to the shared directory via `SMB` (Samba). You will find lots of discussion on this. One tutorial http://www.raspberrypihelp.net/tutorials/12-mount-a-samba-share-on-raspberry-pi

If you have more specific questions clarity your question.

Answer (score 0):

Access your windows shared folders on the RPI using `mount` command.
Everything well explained in [this link](https://rasspberrypi.wordpress.com/2012/09/04/mounting-and-automounting-windows-shares-on-raspberry-pi/).

Note: I getting "no such file or directory" errors until I realized it's better edit `etc/fstab` file and then run `mount` command.